# Proper way to setup propensity matching

Tags: r, matching

I'm involved in a study where we want to examine the effects of two different types of implant on a variety of health outcomes.  We've collected a ton of data on about 200 patients who received either type of implant and we were about to examine outcomes but we realized that our patient populations for each implant type were a little bit different (due to a variety of reasons like which surgeon was doing what operation/time period/etc...).

So the other investigators I'm working with suggested we match our patients into two groups that have relatively similar values of these covariates:  **age** (a number), **obesity** (true/false), **smoking** history (four levels), **radiation** history (true/false), and **plane of reconstruction** (subpectoral versus prepectoral) for the surgery.

So, given I was new to matching, I followed [this tutorial](https://sejdemyr.github.io/r-tutorials/statistics/tutorial8.html) to match based on those covariates, but then I realized I ran into some problems.  When I used the code:

```
mod_match <- matchit(graft ~ Age + other_comorbidities___4 + smoking + radiation + subpec_vs_prepec, method = "nearest", data = Data_nomiss)

dta_m <- match.data(mod_match)
```

to match my data, it returned data that was wildly NOT matched.  I.e. obesity in one group was 70% while 20% in the other group.  Age was decades different, etc..

From what I can determine from answers [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56951408/matchit-function-returns-equal-continuous-variable-but-unequal-categorical-varia), it seems like my problem stems from matching on the propensity score specifically, rather than matching on the covariates (which it sounds like is what I wanted to do).  It also seems like factor variables are treated differently than continuous ones and can cause some problems.

So my question is two-fold:

- If I'm trying to match groups that have relatively similar values for those 5 covariates, should I still use the matchIt package? (If so I would love input on which "method" and how to setup that code.  For instance I didn't understand his comment about "exact" in that answer)
- If there is a different package or method to match, I would love some
  direction on what that is called/where to look.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching is in art in the sense that you may need to try a variety of specifications to find one that works for your data, if at all (I'll get back to the "if at all" at the end). 1:1 propensity score matching without replacement is almost certainly the worst matching method to use, especially in your case with so few observations. It is the default because other methods can be layered on top of it to create a matching specification that works. You need to try many different matching specifications to find one that achieves balance without destroying your (effective) sample size. Did you try full matching (setting `method = "full"`)? Did you try cardinality matching (setting `method = "cardinality"`)? Did you try adding a caliper (using the `caliper` argument)? Did you try adding an exact matching restriction (using the `exact` argument)? There are so many ways to customize a matching specification, and all the ones available in `MatchIt` are described in the Matching Methods [vignette](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/articles/matching-methods.html). I also highly recommend using the `MatchIt` [tutorial vignette](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/articles/MatchIt.html) instead of the one you found.

My next point is whether matching is the right method for you. Why do you want to use matching over other methods of confounding control, like regression? With such a small sample, it is probable that variability in the effect estimate will be vastly greater than the bias that matching would eliminate that wouldn't be eliminated with regression. If you have a problem with separability number of events per variable, try penalized logistic regression (e.g., using the `brglm2` package). It may also be the case that you tiny sampel simply doesn't contain enough information for you to reliably remove confounding and estimate an effect with precision, and you will need to decide on a tradeoff between the two or collecting more data.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful comments!  To answer some of those questions, I'll have to discuss with my co-investigators first.  Sounds like (and this may be just opinion), the best bet is to try several methods and see how well they each "match"?  I.e. there may not be one absolutely best rule we should use. Correct?

Comment: That is correct and a given in matching. As long as you don't involve the outcome in your analysis, you are not "cheating". You should report your failed attempts to match in your manuscript so readers understand that matching is an iterative process and you didn't just choose the one that gave you the best effect estimate.